# Javascript Canvas Not Able To Be Cleared After Transform

Tags: javascript, html, animation, canvas, transform

I'm trying to draw any amount of images onto a canvas while being able to zoom in/out using the `mousewheel` event, but when adjusting the canvas scale, sometimes the images overlap and the canvas doesn't clear.

Here I get the canvas, create the starting scale, image, and add the eventlistener when it is loaded:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("Canvas") // Canvas
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d") // Context
var scale = 1 // Stored Canvas Scale
var image = new Image() // Random Image
image.src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f1/Heart_coraz%C3%B3n.svg/1200px-Heart_coraz%C3%B3n.svg.png"
image.onload = () => {console.log("Running..."); canvas.addEventListener("mousewheel", MouseWheelHandler)}
```

Next, the reDraw() method clears the canvas and draws any number of images (between 10, or so) onto the canvas, while compensating for the positioning of the images:

```
function reDraw() { // Draw Image(s)
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height) // Clear Canvas 
  var maxX = parseInt(Math.random()*10) // Set Max Length
  var maxY = parseInt(Math.random()*10) // Set Max Height
  var size = 32; // Set Image Size
  
  for (var i=0; i<maxX; i++) {
    ctx.drawImage(image, canvas.width/2, canvas.height/2-(size*(maxY-i-1)), size, size)
    for (var c=0; c<maxY; c++) {
      ctx.drawImage(image, canvas.width/2-(size*(maxX-i-1)), canvas.height/2-(size*(maxY-i-1)), size, size)
    }
  }
}
```

Finally, the MouseWheelHandler() method gets the mousewheel data and adjusts the canvas scale accordingly:

```
function MouseWheelHandler(e) {
  var e = window.event || e;
  var delta = e.wheelDelta || -e.detail
  if (scale+(delta/Math.abs(delta*10)) >= 0.1) { // Prevent zooming out further than 10% of view
    var zoom = (1+(delta/Math.abs(delta*10))) // Set the zoom
    scale += (delta/Math.abs(delta*10)) // Set the scale (No less than 0.1)
    ctx.transform(zoom,0,0,zoom,-(zoom-1)*canvas.width/2,-(zoom-1)*canvas.height/2)
    reDraw()
  }
}
```

My problem is that if I zoom too far out, the canvas isn't getting cleared and the images appear to kind of echo, or layer on top of one another. I've tried doing `ctx.clearRect()` with numbers larger and smaller than the canvas size, but it still results in overlapping images.

I just want to be able to zoom in/out and have the canvas only display what was drawn after the `MouseWheelHandler` runs.

Comment: try : `ctx.clearRect(0,0,ctx.canvas.width,ctx.canvas.height);`

Comment: @debugger, same thing.

Comment: I'm  missing something - where is scale used?

Comment: @AHaworth Scale is just used so I can tell the amplification of the zoom. Essentially, it starts at 1 and if you zoom in/out it goes up/down by 0.1. Just used to ensure it can't be zoomed less than a scale value of 0.1